# Webpack is not updating content of dist/index.html after changes in src/index.html have been made

Tags: node.js, webpack

I'm currently facing difficulties with configuring webpack for my project.

My objective is to create a TypeScript "app" with Jest installed, and I want to organize all my source files within the `src` folder. These source files include `src/index.html`, `src/style.css`, and `src/index.ts`. The desired outcome is to have webpack automatically copy or build these files to the `dist` folder, resulting in `dist/index.html`, `dist/style.css`, and `dist/index.js`.

The main issue I'm encountering is that the `dist/index.html` file is only updated when I manually run `npm run build`. However, I want webpack to handle this automatically while the webpack server is running.

I've already engaged in a lengthy discussion with ChatGPT and attempted various fixes, but I seem to be stuck in a loop.

Here's my current `webpack.config.js`:

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.ts',
    output: {
        filename: 'index.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
        ],
    },
    devServer: {
        static: {
            directory: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        },
        compress: true,
        port: 9000,
        hot: true,
        headers: {
            "Cache-Control": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate",
            "Pragma": "no-cache",
            "Expires": "0",
        },
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html',
            filename: 'index.html',
        }),
    ],
};
```

Edit:
Here is my `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "typescript-webpack-jest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack serve --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.12",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^12.0.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.6.0",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.5.1",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3",
    "webpack": "^5.90.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.1"
  }
}
```

Furthermore, I've noticed that when I make updates to `src/index.html`, the developer console's network tab shows that an `update.js` file is loaded, but the page does not automatically reload with the changes. Only manual reloading reflects the updates, and even then, the `dist/index.html` file is not updated.

Can someone please provide assistance in getting my setup to work as intended?